# Self hosted service to monitor a HTTP endpoint (for change) and trigger an event

Tags: web-apps, automation, self-hosted, http, rest

I am looking for a web-based application where you can set up HTTP monitors (to monitor for changes specifically but support for more triggers like HTTP status would also be nice) which then fire REST requests. The use case would be to periodically check another rest endpoint for a change (e.g. a GitHub repository or Docker image) so that you can trigger a dependent application that you manage to be rebuilt.

Although polling is typically seen as a bad thing and webhooks exist for a reason, they only work if you are the owner of the repository on most services that I would want to do this with. GitHub/Docker won't allow me to create a webhook on a project that isn't mine.

I would like the application to have a web interface where jobs and logs can be viewed and managed. If there are paid products I wouldn't rule it out but if there is also a free alternative I would like to be able to compare what was offered. It is also required that the service can be self hosted behind a firewall as an online service would not have access to the services that need triggering.

If something like this doesn't exist it might be a nice project (for myself or another) as I can't see it being too complicated using Django and Celery.

Comment: So basically you want an HTTP monitor where if there is a change, it fires a REST request? Do you mind paying for a product or does it have to be free?

Comment: @Tom That's right - preferably it would have a web interface for viewing the rules/jobs and logs. I wouldn't rule out a paid product but if a free alternative exists then it would be nice to be able to weigh up/compare the two. I updated the question with this additional information.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend

http://www.phpservermonitor.org
http://docs.phpservermonitor.org/en/latest/intro.html

Easy to setup and easy to use with log retention etc. However it does not have REST calls as a notification feature but I believe that the notifications to Clickatell et al (which is supported by PhpServerMonitor) is done by REST calls so I think it would be doable for you to adjust it to your preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Would [IFTTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IFTTT) fit the bill? I've never used it, thus I don't know their selection of so called "triggers" - but in case they offer a "web polling" one, you could set up a "then do this" hook.

If you'd rather prefer a non SaaS solution and host it yourself, go to github and search for "[IFTTT clone](https://github.com/search?q=ifttt%20clone&type=Repositories)", there's quite a selection of apps you can host yourself.

Comment: The issue with IFTTT is that it is not self hosted meaning I can't put it inside my firewall. I will take a look to see if it can do what I need and if there is a way I can let just IFTTT through the firewall. Although I wrote "self hosted" in the title, I forgot to specify this requirement in my description. I have now updated. Thanks for the contribution though. I will still check if its possible with IFTTT so that if others are looking and don't have the restriction of self-hosted they will know if they can or can't use IFTTT.

Comment: Ah, shoot... I forgot about the self-hosted bit while reading through. But a quick look at github brought numerous [ITFFF clones](https://github.com/search?q=ifttt+clone&type=Repositories) up - didn't try any of 'em, but some might be actually working and could be self-hosted.

Comment: Huginn looks promising: https://github.com/cantino/huginn